# reference to a non-shared member vb.net error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

```
Public Class frmwelcome3
    Dim holsearch = frmholidaysearch

    Private Sub btnholidayswelcome3_Click(sender As Object, 
               e As EventArgs) Handles btnholidayswelcome3.Click
        Me.Hide()
        holsearch.Show()
```

I get the error... referemce to a non-shared member of vb.net error

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `holsearch` is not an instanced object

Comment: where did the `frmholidaysearch` come from?

Comment: .. Replace `=` with `As New`......

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new instance of the class `frmholidaysearch`. Replace `=` with `As New`.